# Borderlands plumber style achievement

Tags: achievements, borderlands

What is the 'kill an enemy plumber-style' achievement in borderlands?
What exactly do I need to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just jump onto one of the Skag Pups in the starting area a couple of times to kill it. Bingo.

Answer (score 7):

The achievement refers to [a particularly famous plumber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario) and his favorite method of killing enemies:

> Kill an enemy by jumping on top of its head. [Video example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqccnVH-UrE)

Answer (score 1):

If your skags are too high of a level bring their health down to a sliver without killing them and then jump on their head for the kill.